# How to call an Ajax-enabled WCF service with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, wcf, jquery

I have this `Aja.svc` in my root folder

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Aja
{
    [WebGet]
    [OperationContract]
    public string Hi()
    {
        return "hi world!";
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to do this:

```
$.get('Aja.svc?method=Hi', function(d) { alert(d.d); });
```

In **firebug** I see that the result is **HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.**

I use .net 3.5, jquery 1.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if WCF is installed

```
   $.get('Aja.svc/Hi', function(d) { alert(d.d); });
```

Comment: could you try your code by setting explicetly the webhost address? like "htt p://yourdomain/Aja.svc/Hi"? does it work this way?

Comment: @Saaman tried it (although I see in firebug that the url is correct), same result

Comment: @Saaman it looks like your way method=Hi I get a bit different error 404.17, I've edited my question please take a look

Comment: @Omu : Are you running under IIS7.0? it seems to be an error of IIS configuration... can you check if your IIS configuration & appPool configuration allows asp.Net correctly? I don't know maybe you already configured your IIS correctly.